# Get UINavController from subview of UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I added a custom subview to a UIViewController's content view. From that subview, how can I get a reference to the superview's controller?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is "You're Doing It Wrong™" ;-)

You shouldn't need to reference to a view controller from a view, and you certainly should never retain a view controller in one of your views -- or you'll end up with a retain loop and leak memory.

Cocoa provides multiple patterns to solve this problem:

- **Use a delegate:** Define a protocol called DemoViewDelegate and add a delegate property to DemoView. Then have your view controller implement this protocol. *Important: delegates should never be retained! Any delegate property you create should be set to `assign`.* See [Apple's Delegation docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or just google "delegation pattern".
- **Use the responder chain:** Call UIApplication's `sendAction:to:from:forEvent:` and leave `to:` set to `nil` to have your action message automatically routed up the responder chain to your view controller. See [Apple's Responder docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) and the more detailed [Action Messages docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html).
- **Use a notification:** Less common in this particular scenario, but you could also have your view controller listen for a notification, which the view sends.

Comment: Even if the design is fixed, it would be interesting to find the mapping from views to view controllers. We all know it's there, hidden in some private API just waiting to be abused...